# Which Perl web framework should I use for a static HTML application?

Tags: html, css, perl, frameworks

I am about a develop a simple web application (5-6 static pages). Is there a framework I could use for this? I can just write these HTML pages without a framework but I would like a framework as it will better handle header, footer, and CSS throughout the website.

I have a Perl script that will be modifying these HTML pages daily. And I don't need a database.

Comment: What exactly is a "static HTML application"? I'm curious. It sounds contradictory.

Answer (score 10):

[ttree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template%3a%3aTools%3a%3attree) is made for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can just generate the static HTML with the Perl script. That way you don't have to re-type the footer etc in each HTML file.

Used to have a page that was generated each hour with /bin/sh and various unix tools :)

edit:
And, as Ignacio said, you can still use template engines etc.

Answer (score 1):

For projects that are too small to use a full-fledged web framework, I usually write a class (module) for handling the layout. Then each page in the project would be a Perl script that uses the module's functions to print the header and footer. It would look something like this.

```
my $page = GauravWebpageClass->new(-title => 'Page Title');
$page->add_style('anotherStyle.css');
$page->add_script('fancyJavascript.js');
$page->print_header();

# Print your content here
# Print your content here
# Print your content here

$page->print_footer();
```

That's the basic idea. It assumes you know how to write [object-oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html). Let me know if you need help with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used a makefile that just ran various template pieces through a template engine (Genshi in my case, but the exact details don't matter) to generate the static pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [Blueprint CSS Framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), which helps to standardize layout across different browsers.